# Cant update Grub , /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: r#: not found

Tags: boot, grub2, pcie

[image]

on using `sudo update-grub`  i get an error

so the error is `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: r#: not found`

and due to this i have to edit grub temporarily every time i boot up just to prevent PCI bus error

Answer (score 1):

the solution That works with me is to open the grub and edit the first line from

`r# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update`

to

`# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update`

Answer (score 0):

Any comment/remark line that does not begin with a # will cause this error.
A comment/remark line is a line of text explaining how to treat the next command line.

An example that appears in an Ubuntu `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1
```

In the above example, the second line (command line) will be executed
because it has been uncommented, the file has been edited and the leading # deleted.  It does NOT begin with a `#` as it does in the original `/etc/default/grub` file.

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and make sure all text lines begin with a `#`.

Save `/etc/default/grub` file and run 'sudo update-grub' before rebooting.